# How to set ExpandableListView child as not enabled

Tags: android

Is there a way to set a child on an [ExpandableListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html) as not enabled? I have a header in the children group and I don't want it to be highlighted when clicked. Not an actual header, just a child with a different layout.

What I'm looking for is something like [ListAdapter#isEnabled()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListAdapter.html#isEnabled%28int%29) but there is no such method in the ExpandableListAdapter class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [isChildSelectable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListAdapter.html#isChildSelectable%28int,%20int%29). This will allow you to set the group/child as selectable or not. Selectable is synonymous to enabled.

Comment: Note that this **doesn't work for the group** itself, only for its children.